flutter app OTP screen not showing after receiving OTP from firebase
This screen appear after entering mobile number
i have created an app using flutter in my app i am using firebase phone authentication after developing my app i put my app in playstore i try to remove the robot verification from my app and replace with play integrity api now my app doesn't do robot verification when my user click on the login button after entering mobile number my user receives otp but the otp entering screen was not appearing so this is my problem
i have uploaded required key i have added sha 1 sha 256 from the play store,debug key,and release key from my project now my firebase has 3 sha1 and 3 sha256 key in my google gloud i have linked my project also in play console in api integrity i have linked project but the the api integration screen look like this when i click on integrate integrity api button it redirect me to the documentation.and more thing for play integrity api integration i have only do things externally but i haven't even modify the code related to authentication.so what will be the solution 1.when my user click on the log in button after entering mobile number he receives otp but the otp screen not appearing to enter otp 2.why my playconsoles app integrity screen looking like this it shows integration started 3.do i have to modify my code for play integrity and everything works fine in debugmode This is my Play console app integrity screen
